# скорее versus поскорее

Tags: значения

**скоро** means *quickly*, and **скорее** is the comparative form of **скоро**.

But what is the difference between **скорее** and **поскорее**? Don't they both fundamentally mean *quicker*? Or are they not interchangeable?

Compare:

1) постарайтесь увидеть этот фильм **скорее**.

2) постарайтесь увидеть этот фильм **поскорее**.

Comment: I would say "Постарайтесь **посмотреть** этот фильм поскорее".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, "*скорее*" may also mean "*rather*", which is not the case for "*поскорее*".

Next, when both actually mean "*quicker*", they are synonyms, yet *поскорее* sounds more natural if used alone, while *скорее* is usually better if used in a "full" comparative construction (i.e. "quicker than smth."). That is in your example sentence, I would certainly choose *поскорее*.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that these words are synonyms in the most cases, but in your example the second option IMO looks *more Russian*.

Maybe it's because `Поскорее` means something like `the earlier the better` and not just `quicker`.